# Accepted plural form of "Hijab"

Tags: grammatical-number, translation, loanwords, irregular

Although ***hijab*** is not an English word, it is commonly used in English to describe the head scarf worn by many Moslem women.

I was pretty sure I had just heard Christiane Amanpour of CNN call the plural "**hijub**", and that made me go to look up the correct plural.

There seems to be a disagreement among different sources.

[WordForum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plural-of-hijab.876132/) calls the plural **hujub** (singular hijab)

[Wikionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hijab) says it is **hijabs**.

In a case like this, where the original language has a plural different from a usage in English, which should be used? [I am aware of the precedents set by Greek plurals, and I would like to side-step all that.]

Comment: Update: at the moment, BBC is advertising a special on fashion and _hijabis_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at usage, according to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hujub%2Chijabs&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chujub%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chijabs%3B%2Cc0)*** ***hijabs*** is the more common form.

> "English has borrowed words from nearly every language with which it has come into contact, and particularly for nouns from Latin, Greek, Hebrew, and French, it has often borrowed their foreign plurals as well. ***But when loan words cease to seem 'foreign,' and if their frequency of use in English increases, they very often drop the foreign plural in favor of a regular English -s.***  Thus at any given time we can find some loan words in divided usage, with both the foreign plural (e.g., indices) and the regular English plural (e.g., indexes) in Standard use. And occasionally we’ll find a semantic distinction between the two acceptable forms, as with the awe-inspiring Hebrew cherubim and the chubby English cherubs."

(Kenneth G. Wilson, The Columbia Guide to Standard American English. Columbia University Press, 1993)

Comment: From Google books it appears that the s plural took off in the early 2000. I think people  are more confortable  with the anglicised plural.

Comment: On the other hand, *cherubim* beats *cherubs*, so maybe it's a Semitic thing.

Comment: @deadrat I would argue *cherubs* and *cherubim* nowadays refer to different things, likewise *antennae* and *antennas*,  or *mediums* and *media*.

Comment: @choster I'm already half convinced. The earthly beings (like the little bastards in my neighborhood on whose behalf I'm being asked to raise my taxes) would be called cherubs, not cherubim. The heavenly versions I think take both plurals, but preferentially the Semitic plural in the company of seraphim, which is the clear favorite in multitudes. What do you think?

Comment: @deadrat Agreed, and I'd further note that the *-im* suffix seems to be a much more familiar borrowing than *-ot* — I'd wager more AmE speakers, for instance, recognize *goyim* than *mitzvot(h)* as plurals. Maybe we borrow more masculine nouns than feminine ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hijabs sounds reasonable. While I don't see it common to pluralize new foreign words as in the original language, you can always circumvent the problem with *hijab scarves*, signifying that particular *veil* headscarf (حجاب), as opposed to a Russian *babushka* kerchief.

Of course we do use established plurals like *data* and *alumni*.

Comment: A hijab is a scarf, so you're recommending scarf scarf? (BTW, I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: Neither am I the DVer; I was actually looking for a plural, not a way to skirt the issue.

Comment: @deadrat - As I understand it, the hijab serves more as a form of veil than scarf.